# Best way to define error code and error message mapping in .NET

Tags: .net, error-handling

I want to create custom error code and message mapping file. Currently I use `Dictionary<int, string>` to store them but I think they may have better way to achieve this.

If there is common practice to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe rather have a look at using a resource in the project

[Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I think using resource file in this case is not appropriate, because my error code is int but resource name is string. This mean there will be boxing and un-boxing during get and set error code. BTW if you can suggest me how to change type of name of resource file from string to int, I'd appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define an enum for your error codes that map to a resource file, that way they can be esaly manage, localized, etc.